# Can you have apache-tomcat and another server like wampp or xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, wamp

I am new to Web Development but I have experience in Java, C/C++,Unix Scripting and basic SQL.  I have apache-tomcat server because I downloaded Java EE but recently I wanted to start added PHP to my html and I have to download a server like wampp or xampp to run php files.  But I downloaded xampp and when I tried to reach my localhost my browser froze up, I tried it multiple times but no luck reaching my local server.  Then I decided to try it on wamp and the same thing happened.  Can you have two different kinds of servers on your PC even if only one is turned on at a time?

Answer (score 1):

No you can get PHP to run out of a TomCat Web Server.

[See this](http://tomcatenv.awardspace.com/) somewhere in the middle of it he tells you how to download a PECL extension that will allow TomCat and the PHP interpreter to become friend.